# PointerLockControls, changing center of camera rotation

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using PointerLockControls and KeyboardControls (WASD) for a classic First Person 3D application. I am wondering if there is an easy way to change the center of the camera rotation in order to create a third person perspective like in Fortnite.
Thank you very much!